# Fourier transform of Coulomb potential in 1D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform

The Fourier transform of the Coulomb potential $V(r)=\frac{k}{r}$ is typically evaluated by computing the Fourier transform of the Yukawa potential given by $V_{Yukawa}=\frac{ke^{-\epsilon r}}{r}$ and taking the limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ after the transform has been computed. This is possible in 2 and 3 dimensions because the volume element contains a factor of $r$ and $r^2$ respectively that cancel the factor of $r$ in the denominator of the potential and keeps the integrand finite at $r\rightarrow 0$. But in 1 dimension, there is no such factor in the volume element and the integral diverges. Is there a way around this complication? This Fourier transform of a potential shows up in recasting a two-body operator, given in first quantized notation, to second quantized notation, and if the two representations are equivalent, then there must be a way to handle this divergence in the Fourier transform for the 1D Coulomb potential. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is no Coulomb potential in one dimension to begin with, if I understand dimensionality arguments correctly. The equivalent potential in two dimensions is logarithmic and in one dimension it would be a constant, wouldn't it? At least that's what I remember vaguely from a class some 3+ decades ago.

Comment: You're right, it would be a constant and I think you can show that using Gauss's Law. But nomenclature aside, I'm talking about a $\frac{1}{r}$ potential in 1D (which probably isn't called a Coulomb potential). Does the Fourier transform of this potential exist?

Comment: As a function? No. In the sense of a distribution/linear operator? I believe so, you just have to pick the right linear space on which this object is well defined. The last time I took functional analysis was 30 years ago, so I can't tell you whether Mr. Banach or Mr. Sobolev is your friend, though. I am sure a more mathematically inclined person can chime in.